# App not coming in ICS market android

Tags: android

I have added these permissions in the android market place.

```
<!-- Camera -->
<!-- Required to be able to access the camera device. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />    
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

and then i have uploaded the app to Android Market. But my is not visible in the Android 4.0.3 tablet market. But visible in Android HoneyComb market place.

Minsdkversion: 12
Target       : 12

Is any thing that i made mistake???

Comment: on which devices are you checking? most tablets don't have a rear camera, so it makes sense that you app won't be visible.

Comment: remove the Target : 12. then it will detect.

Comment: i have removed the target. Still not visible in ics but coming in honey comb

Comment: I just removed the target.  I did nothing.  The issue is, it was taking some time to get updated. Now it was visible in ics also..

Answer (score 3):

The target sdk version should always be the highest available. So use the 4.1 sdk and set target to 16.

Comment: My app is set to target 14. Does that mean I cant install it using the APK directly, on 15 and above?

Comment: You always should set a min SDK and the target sdk should be higher than the min SDK if possible. The app will be installable on devices with 14, 15 & 16 (and everything else that will be coming) but it will always adapt the 14 look & feel + functions.

Comment: Yep, Min is 10, and yea setting a target, increased the visuals on the API 14 androids. Thanks for the info :)